# databricks cli returning error: "Error: invalid scheme: 'dbfs"

Tags: windows, cmd, databricks-cli

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
C:\Users\user123>databricks fs cp 'dbfs:/databricks/init/myinit.sh' myinit.sh
```

However, I get the error:

```
ERROR failed execution pid=1234 exit_code=1 error="invalid scheme: 'dbfs"
```

Running with the `--debug` flag:

```
C:\Users\user123>databricks fs cp --debug 'dbfs:/databricks/init/myinit.sh' myinit.sh
00:02:04  INFO start pid=1234 version=0.212.2 args="databricks, fs, cp, --debug, 'dbfs:/databricks/init/myinit.sh', myinit.sh"
00:02:04 DEBUG Loading DEFAULT profile from C:\Users\user123/.databrickscfg pid=1234 sdk=true
Error: invalid scheme: 'dbfs
00:02:04 ERROR failed execution pid=1234 exit_code=1 error="invalid scheme: 'dbfs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using double quotes resolved this issue:

```
C:\Users\user123>databricks fs cp "dbfs:/databricks/init/myinit.sh" myinit.sh
```